# how to get html output page in ABOT C# Web Crawler?

Tags: c#, web-crawler

i am trying to make web crawler using ABOT in c#.i have searched many example and added the ABOT web crawler. from that i can get only log output instead of Html page output.i want to get html page output only.because that HTML output is input for HTML Agility Tool.
Help me to get HTML output from ABOT web crawler in C#.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Explained [here on the quickstart page](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot#quick-start)

```
//Create an instance of the crawler and subscribe to the PageCrawlCompleted event
PoliteWebCrawler crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler();
crawler.PageCrawlCompleted += crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted;

//The event handler method
void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
{
    CrawledPage crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;

    if (crawledPage.WebException != null || crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page failed {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page succeeded {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);


    //crawledPage.Content.Text //raw html
    //crawledPage.HtmlDocument //lazy loaded html agility pack object (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)
    //crawledPage.CSDocument   //lazy loaded cs query object (CsQuery.Cq)
}
```

Comment: I'm using v1.5.0 and the default `PoliteWebCrawler` / default `CrawlConfiguration` does not set any `DownloadableContentTypes` so you will need to be sure and set it to something like : `crawlConfig.DownloadableContentTypes = "text/html, text/plain, application/json"`

Comment: @sjdirect `crawledPage.RawContent` in last version is deprecated. So how we can get raw html string? Is `e.CrawledPage.Content.ToString()` the alternative way?

Comment: @guidomocha Content.Text is the way to access the raw html. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
{
    CrawledPage crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;
    crawledPage.Content.Text // HTML

}
```

Comment: Could you add some context to this? What's different about this as compared to sjdirect's answer? (Aside from being more minimal.)

Comment: His answer was so big that I didn't find the correct property. But he helped me to understand that I can get on "ProcessPageCrawlCompleted". Then I debugged that event and quickly discover the answer. My main goal here is to be minimal, as you said. That's what I would like to see if I was a visitor.

Answer (score 0):

to get htmlpage only use:

```
crawledPage.Content
```

inside of the function

```
`static void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)`
```

for example:

```
static void crawler_ProcessPageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
    {
        CrawledPage crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;

        if (crawledPage.WebException != null || crawledPage.HttpWebResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page failed {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Crawl of page succeeded {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(crawledPage.Content.Text))
            Console.WriteLine("Page had no content {0}", crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

        var htmlAgilityPackDocument = crawledPage.HtmlDocument; //Html Agility Pack parser
        var angleSharpHtmlDocument = crawledPage.AngleSharpHtmlDocument; 

        //get content

        Console.WriteLine(crawledPage.Content);


    }
```